# Hide dynamically created child elements of a grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid

I have a grid in which I have created and added elements from the code behind.

```
Dim staffImgLeft As New Controls.Image()
staffImgLeft.Name = "StaffImgLeft"
mainGrid.Children.Add(staffImgLeft)
```

When I am attempt to remove the child elements from the grid they are not being removed.

```
mainGrid.Children.Remove(mainGrid.FindName("StaffImgLeft"))
```

There are no errors when the code runs.  Can anyone advise why my code isnt working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindName` returns null, hence nothing gets removed.

[Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) the name instead of setting it to make it findable:

```
mainGrid.RegisterName("StaffImgLeft",staffImgLeft)
```

Comment: As these two sections of code are in different methods, would I need to define a global variable of staffImgLeft to achieve this?

Comment: No, just replace the line where you set the name with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RegisterName` and `UnregisterName` so you have an accessor that simplifies access to the NameScope registration.

```
Dim staffImgLeft As New Controls.Image();
staffImgLeft.Name = "StaffImgLeft";
mainGrid.Children.Add(staffImgLeft);
// register name
mainGrid.RegisterName(staffImgLeft.Name, StaffImgLeft);

// then remove
mainGrid.Children.Remove(mainGrid.FindName("StaffImgLeft"));
// un-register if you intend to re-register an element with the same name later.
mainGrid.UnregisterName("StaffImgLeft");
```

You should probably read about WPF XAML Namescopes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx

Comment: Thanks Fraser, your example was great.  I gave the answer to HB as he was first in, however I thank you for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated.